# How to activate translation for all management commands by default?

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n, django-management-command

I need translation to be activated in all of my django management commands by default. Currently I'm putting this line of code in all my management commands:

```
translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

And sometimes I forget to consider it in my command. I need it to send translated notifications.  Is there any way to activate translation for all of management commands by default?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into `BaseCommand`'s source I figured out django is disabling translation and I could just prevent that by adding an attribute inside my `Command` class:

```
class CoreBaseCommand(BaseCommand):

    leave_locale_alone = True
```

I did put that line in my custom BaseCommand to be applied in all inherited commands.